# animate() jquery failed in my case

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.more').click(function() {
        var thumbsBlock = $(this).siblings('.thubmnailsWrap');

        $($(this), thumbsBlock).animate({
            'left' : "-=60px" //moves left
        });
    });
});
```

I use siblings and expect .thubmnailsWrap to move along with .more but failed. check my demo here http://jsfiddle.net/pdjkh69m/4/

I solved it, here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/pdjkh69m/8/ but I wonder why in my previous code, the multiple selector jst does not work, any idea? I kinda want to continue with duplicated code.

Comment: 'move along with more' means what ... what you want exactly????

Answer (score 1):

Your css is incorrect, you need to use class selector **`.`** for the div to get `position:absolute` for animate to work.

Also use `.add()` to add another element to your jQuery object

```
thumbsBlock.add(this).animate({
    'left': "-=60px"
},1000);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pdjkh69m/6/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {


    $('.more').click(function () {


        var thumbsBlock = $(this).siblings('.thubmnailsWrap');

        $(thumbsBlock).animate({
            'left': "-=60px"
        });

    });
});
```

this is the code are you looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
$($(this), thumbsBlock)
```

this is wrong method

this works

http://jsfiddle.net/pdjkh69m/10/